# socket_accept seems to hang on the first connection

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple listener on port 8195. When I try the following code block in PHP CLI conditions, it only shows 'Test' once, then hangs. If I delete the file 'votifier.run', the file designed to be the on/off switch, it still continues to hang. It never shows 'Client connected'.

Furthermore, if I try to connect to the host via Telnet on port 8195 while the script is running, I simply get a connection failed message. It's like it's looking for one connection and just not giving up.

```
// Set the IP and port to listen to
$address = 'localhost';
$port = 8195;

// Create a TCP Stream socket
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
// Bind the socket to an address/port
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);
// Start listening for connections
socket_listen($sock);

// Loop continuously
while ( file_exists('votifier.run') ) {
    echo 'Test';
    $client = socket_accept($sock);
    if( $client ) {
            echo 'Client connected';
            // Don't hang on slow connections
            socket_set_timeout($client, 5);

            // Send them our version
            socket_write("VOTIFIER MCWEBLINK\n");

            // Read the 256 byte block
            $block = socket_read($client, 256);
            ...
```

**The answer:**
socket_accept() will usually hang until a connection is made. If a connection attempt was made, the script would continue, but because the socket was being created on localhost, it would only accept connections to it *from* localhost.

The fix is to use your external IP rather than 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'. Then you can Telnet to it.

Comment: Try passing 6 (tcp) as the protocol to socket_create

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but could it be that the address you are trying to bind to should not be a hostname?

> If the socket is of the AF_INET family, the address is an IP in dotted-quad notation (e.g. 127.0.0.1).

**EDIT**

Ok, I've taken your script and tried to reproduce your error but couldn't. There are a couple of flaws in it but none that would cause a telnet client's connection attempt to fail.

Since none of the aforementioned applies, let's go thru the checklist one by one:

- sockets module loaded/compiled
- localhost does resolve to 127.0.0.1
- the port isn't taken by any other application running
- there's no rule of any sort of firewall that would prevent communication between the telnet client and your server
- the machine which you connect from is allowed to connect to the server host (try the same host if it isn't)
- the file that's being checked in the while-loop does exist
- you are sure that there isn't another fatal error within your script that would prevent the snippet you posted from running

These are all the possible error sources I can think of, atm. Try fixing up the minor flaws first, then go thru the checklist.

```
if( $client ) {
    echo 'Client connected';
    // Don't hang on slow connections
    socket_set_option(
        $client,
        SOL_SOCKET,
        SO_RCVTIMEO | SO_SNDTIMEO,
        array('sec' => 5, 'usec' => 0)
    );

    // Send them our version
    socket_write($client, "VOTIFIER MCWEBLINK\n");
                 ^^^^^^^

    // Read the 256 byte block
    $block = socket_read($client, 256);
```

Comment: I did just notice that actually and tried it with 127.0.0.1; no avail though. Same results.

Comment: Did you check whether the port is currently in use?

Comment: There is no error. The value of socket_last_error is Success just before socket_accept, and nothing afterwards as it is hanging on socket_accept.

Comment: Thank you, it turned out that socket_accept() will hang until a connection attempt is made. When I tried Telnet-ing, it wasn't getting through - possibly because of a firewall - and so the script never continued. I tried a simple fsockopen and fgets in another PHP script and got the response I was looking for.

Comment: It wasn't a firewall problem. The socket had to be created with the external IP 63.***.***.226 rather than 127.0.0.1 Now I can Telnet!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using threads. If the client never sends anything your code will block in the read() method. Each accepted socket should be completely handled in a new thread.

Comment: If the client doesn't send anything, the socket will time out in 5 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check this:
[PHP Votifier example for Minecraft Topsites](http://topg.org/php_votifier)

It explains how the code works, it's the basic function that makes the encryption, fills up the 256 blank spaces and sends the packet too. You can work a little with it as you may want to improve it.

You can see a live demo of the running php for the plugin here: http://topg.org/test_votifier

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.